# WooCommerce single product page quantity description

Tags: hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to add a description to single product page, just after the - + block (better placing the add-to-cart button below).
Something like this:

- 1 + item/s
  [add-to-cart button]

Might you help me?

Thanks in advance for any advice.
JD